# Metric in $C_{[a,b]}$ and Volterra operator

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, operator-theory

A metric $\rho'_p=max_{t\in [a,b]}|f(t)-g(t)|e^{-pt}$ in $C_{[a,b]}$ is given. I need to prove that $\exists \alpha,\beta>0 \space \forall f,g \in C_{[a,b]} \ \rho'_p(f,g)\alpha \leq \rho_{\infty}(f,g)\leq \rho'_p(f,g)\beta$ and that Volterra operator is a contraction operator in $(C_{[a,b]},\rho'_p)$ when p is big enough. The first statement seems obvious: any $0 < \alpha \leq e^{-pt}$ and $\beta \geq e^{-pt}$ are appropriate, I suppose. But I don't know how to deal with the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
|Vf(t)|
=\bigg|e^{-pt}\,\int_0^t f(s)\,ds\bigg|\leq e^{-pt}\,\int_0^t|f(s)|\,ds\leq\,t\,e^{-pt}\,\|f\|_\infty.
$$
So the question is simply to choose $p$ big enough so that $te^{-pt}\leq1$ on $[0,1]$. If $g(t)=te^{-pt}$, then $g'(t)=(1-tp)\,e^{-pt}$. The only critical point occurs at $t=1/p$, and it's a maximum. Said maximum is
$$
\frac1p\,e^{-p/p}=\frac1{ep}.
$$
So all that's needed is $p>1/e$.